# dynamic product price in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have:

```
scaffold Book name price:integer
scaffold Sale book:referenes quantity:integer
```

Book.rb

```
has_many :sales
```

Sale.rb:

```
belongs_to :book

def total
  book.price * quantity.to_f
end
```

**Problem**: If I want to change the price of a book, it will recalculate all the past sales.

Can I avoid this? By somehow saving the pricing history of a product or having a current_price (active price)?

Comment: sounds like a book can have many prices, right?

Comment: You answered yourself. You'll need to store either sale_price or book_price at the moment of sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't care about the price history of the book, you can just add a `sale_price` to the `Sale` model which will be equal to the price of the book when the sale was created.  If you decide to add that, you may want to consider adding another column that can indicate something about the sale price, ie "10% discount" or "black friday sale".

Good thing about going this way is that you don't need to load the book record anymore to calculate the total price.

```
bin/rails g migration add_sale_price_to_sales
bin/rake db:migrate

# app/model/sale.rb
def total
  sale_price.to_f * quantity.to_d
end
```

In your sales controller, you may want to add something like the following code so that you can set the `sale_price` automatically.

```
def create
  @sale = Sale.new(sale_params)
  @sale.sale_price = @sale.book && @sale.book.price

  if @sale.save
    redirect_to @sale
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column to `sales` table, named `book_price`. Every time a sale is created, you will save book's price at that time to `book_price` column in `sales` table.

Then in your `Sale` model, you can get total by:

```
def total
  book_price * quantity.to_f
end
```

So if you change price of a book, it will not affect on past sales.

Comment: Bad solution: this way we have to type the book_price in manually, each time a sale is created

Answer (score 0):

Change to relationship many-many.

book has many sales and sale has many books.

table book_sales

- id
- book_id
- sale_id

book.rb

```
has_many :book_sales, dependent: :destroy
has_many :sales, through: :book_sales
```

sale.rb

```
has_many :book_sales, dependent: :destroy
has_many :books, through: :book_sales
```

book_sale.rb

```
belongs_to :article
belongs_to :tag

def total
  self.book.price * self.sale.quantity.to_f
end
```

Or you can add field `total` to table book_sales, and update it base on book_id and sale_id by call function total.